# Box2D (LibGdx) getWorldPoint is wrong after collission

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I've just started with Box2D and have come across a strange problem.

I have a simple function to constrain object position to within a predefined area.

I do this by getting the body's world position, checking this against the predefined area's bounding box values, and applying a force to the body to keep it within.

```
 if (bodyWorldPos.x >= worldWidth)
        body.setLinearVelocity(...);
```

This works fine.

However, if the body collides with another body, this simple method stops working.
The body's world position, retrieved like this:

```
body.getWorldPoint(body.getPosition())
```

returns wrong values.

Is this a bug in Box2D for LibGDX or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function getWorldPoint converts a point from 'local coordinates' (relative to the body's 0,0 position) to global coordinates (relative to 0,0 in the world).

I think for this purpose you can just use getPosition() only.